# Flutter app crashes - couldn't find "libflutter.so" Detected on 1 device during testing on google play production

Tags: flutter, dart

```
at androidx.fragment.app.j.onStart(Unknown Source:20)

Exception Process: com.app.myappname, PID: 7468
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-yMJ6sOl-cs_RDOdStLEV3Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.myappname-rjWW-prhm0x9f6Yb3VQpRg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.myappname-rjWW-prhm0x9f6Yb3VQpRg==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.myappname-rjWW-prhm0x9f6Yb3VQpRg==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.myappname-rjWW-prhm0x9f6Yb3VQpRg==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-yMJ6sOl-cs_RDOdStLEV3Q==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.app.myappname-rjWW-prhm0x9f6Yb3VQpRg==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-yMJ6sOl-....
```

I cannot find the crash issue when I tested on the mentioned device virtually from my side. Can anyone please explain?
And my app is not showing on the google play store.
When I click on the console's Google play link, it shows the URL not found.